# Can a WHERE clause predicate evaluate to NULL?

Tags: sql, oracle, null, where-clause, clause

Can a WHERE clause return NULL instead of TRUE or FALSE?
According to the exercise below it is possible, but i can't imagine an example that returns NULL, Is it really possible?

```
4. Which of the following values can NOT be returned after evaluation of WHERE clause
condition?
A.  UNKNOWN
B.  TRUE
C.  FALSE
D.  NULL
Answer: A. If the result of the condition in WHERE clause is not known, NULL is returned. In all
other scenarios, either TRUE or FALSE is returned.
```

Comment: The correct answer is D. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm

Comment: So a `NULL == NULL` would return `UNKNOWN`. Right?

Comment: @SuhasK According to their doc, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, all logical operators evaluate to TRUE, FALSE, and UNKNOWN ([Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions004.htm)) in MySQL UNKNOWN result calls  NULL ([MySQL docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/logical-operators.html)).

According to oracle documentation:

> "To test for nulls, use only the comparison conditions IS NULL and IS
>   NOT NULL. If you use any other condition with nulls and the result
>   depends on the value of the null, then the result is UNKNOWN."

So only TRUE, FALSE, and UNKNOWN can be returned after evaluation.

About your question:

> "Can a WHERE clause return NULL instead of TRUE or FALSE?"

Strictly speaking in Oracle - **NO** because the such result called UNKNOWN.

But in general the meaning of UNKNOWN and NULL is equivalent in this context and it is just a different name for the same thing.
So the example of SQL below (`a.a >= all`) evaluated as UNKNOWN.

```
with table_a as (
select null as a from dual
union all 
select 10 as a from dual
union all 
select 5 as a from dual),
table_b as (
select null as a from dual
union all 
select 10 as a from dual
union all 
select 5 as a from dual)

select * from table_a a where a.a >= all(select a from table_b b)
```

Comment: In Standard SQL, `UNKNOWN` and `NULL` are *distinct* concepts. It's only mysql (so far as I'm aware) that conflates the two.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks, I've corrected, my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As to explain the reason, consider that the SQL language uses a three-value logic: `TRUE`, `FALSE`, and `NULL`. Let's consider this Orders table,

[image]

If we run the following query it wont return rows for CPU and Monitor

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE (qty < 1000 Or qty >= 1000)
```

In this case, for CPU and Monitor condition `(qty < 1000 Or qty >= 1000)`returns neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`. It returns `NULL`. Because logically it is unknown.  So, the result of the condition in `WHERE` clause is unknown and it returned NULL.

You can consider this [reference](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18541).

Comment: Standard SQL describes a three-valued logic where the possible values are `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `UNKNOWN`. It's only mysql, so far as I'm aware, the confuses/conflates `UNKNOWN` and `NULL`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No, MS SQL does the same thing as well. And since `UNKNOWN` and `NULL` are supposed to behave exactly the same, I don't really see why you'd want two keywords for the same thing. In any case, you are right that ANSI SQL has both `UNKNOWN` and `NULL`, for whatever reason.

Comment: @Luaan - not according to [their documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188074.aspx): "The result of a comparison operator has the Boolean data type. This has three values: TRUE, FALSE, and UNKNOWN"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Interesting. They hide it rather well - there is no `unknown` keyword, but `(null = null) is null` is a syntax error (since, as you noted, boolean cannot have a value of `null`). I guess the distinction isn't readily apparent since MS SQL doesn't really have a "public" bool type - only boolean expressions have a type of bool, you can't have bool literals, and you can't have bool variables or columns.

Answer (score 0):

> Not even a NULL can be equal to NULL.

1. The correct way to understand NULL is that it is not a value. Not
   “this is a NULL value” but “this NULL is not a value.”  Everything
   either is a value, or it isn’t.
2. When something is a value, it is “1,” or “hello,” or “green,” or
   “$5.00″ etc – but when something isn’t a value, it just isn’t
   anything at all.
3. SQL represents “this has no value” by the special non-value NULL.
   When someone says “the NULL value,” one should mentally disagree,
   because there’s no such thing. NULL is the complete, total absence
   of any value whatsoever.
   *emphasized text*

***A Non-Technical aspect***

> If you ask two girls, how old they are? may be you would hear them to
>   refuse to answer your question, Both girls are giving you NULL as age
>   and this doesn't mean both have similar age. So there is nothing can
>   be equal to null.

`SELECT 0 IS NULL , 0 IS NOT NULL , '' IS NULL , '' IS NOT NULL, NULL != NULL, NULL = NULL, NULL != '', NULL = ''`